# How to see the path of a NSURL bookmark even if it's unavailable

Tags: objective-c, nsurl

I'm saving a `NSURL` given from a save panel in the user preferences. I'm wondering how to see the path of the URL even if the device on which the file resides is not available, i.e. `[NSURL URLByResolvingBookmarkData:options:bookmarkDataIsStale:error:]` returns `nil`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last known path of a bookmark can be retrieved like so:

```
NSDictionary *values = [[NSURL resourceValuesForKeys:@[NSURLPathKey]
                                    fromBookmarkData:bookmarkData]

NSString *path = [values objectForKey:NSURLPathKey];
```

I made a [full writeup](http://www.mikeabdullah.net/last-known-bookmark-location.html) of this.

Comment: The link is broken :(

Comment: Site should be back up now